# Why using "a" is showing wrong answer but "a+" is showing right answer?

Tags: c, file

I have read same type of questions in stack overflow, but, still I am facing problem with the below code.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    FILE *fp;
    fp=fopen("file.txt","a");
    int num1,num2;
    fscanf(fp,"%d %d",&num1,&num2);
    int sum=num1+num2;
    fprintf(fp,"\n%d",sum);
    fclose(fp);
}
```

It prints a garbage value in file.txt. If I use "a+" then, it prints the right value. What is the problem with this code?

Comment: `fopen("file.txt","a");` You're at the end of file.

Comment: Did you read the man page descriptions of the flags?

Comment: When using "a" cursor is at the end of file and in case of "a+" cursor is at the beginning of the file?@SparKot

Comment: Please provide a [mre] of the problem. In particular, please specify the exact file content before running the problem, and the exact file content after running the program.

Comment: Note: if you had checked the return value from `fscanf` this error would have been more obvious.

Comment: "If I use "a+" then, it prints the right value." -- You cannot rely on this, because your program probably has undefined behavior. You are probably violating the rule of [§7.21.5.3 ¶7](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.5.3p7) of the ISO C standard, which specifies that input shall not be followed by output without an intervening call to a file positioning function (under most conditions). This restriction is also mentioned in [this documentation of the function `fopen`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fopen).

Comment: Since you did not provide a [mre], I cannot tell whether your program is actually invoking undefined behavior when using `"a+"`, because there is an exception to the rule that I mentioned above. Therefore, I can only guess that your program is probably invoking undefined behavior.

Comment: The input file contains 10 15
After running the program the file is 
10 15 
25
if I use "a+".  In case of "a" it shows 
10 15
4208
a garbage value. I hope I have given a minimal reproducible example.@AndreasWenzel

Comment: @Nakib: Yes, that would be a [mre], if you added that information to the question by editing it. Based on the provided information, I believe that your program has undefined behavior in both cases, whether you use `"a"` or `"a+"`. In the former case, the function `fscanf` will likely fail due to the file not being open in read mode, so that `num1` and `num2` have indeterminate values. Attempting to read from an indeterminate value will invoke undefined behavior. I the latter case, [...]

Comment: @Nakib: [...] your program is invoking undefined behavior, due to your program violating the rule that I mentioned in a previous comment. Even if it happens to work in your case, on another computer or compiler, it may not work.

Comment: @Nakib: In your case, I believe it would be best to use `"a+"`, but you should add a call to a file positioning function after reading and before writing, even if it is just a call to `fseek( fp, 0, SEEK_CUR );` (which doesn't really do anything, except satisfy the rule mentioned above). After writing and before reading, it is sufficient to call `fflush( fp );`, but you can also use a file positioning function instead.

Answer (score 1):

You're using `glibc` library : [fopen(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fopen.3.html)

`FILE *fopen(const char *restrict pathname, const char *restrict mode);`

> mode **a+**
>
> Open for reading and appending (writing at end of file).  The file is created if it does not exist.  Output is always appended
> to the  end  of  the file. **POSIX**  is silent on what the initial read position is when using this mode.  For **glibc, the initial file**
> **position for reading is at the beginning of the file**, but for
> Android/BSD/MacOS, the initial file position for reading is at the end of the file.

To get an idea, you need to look into `FILE` data structure:

```
/* The opaque type of streams.  This is the definition used elsewhere.  */
typedef struct _IO_FILE FILE;
```

```
/* The tag name of this struct is _IO_FILE to preserve historic
   C++ mangled names for functions taking FILE* arguments.
   That name should not be used in new code.  */
struct _IO_FILE
{
  int _flags;       /* High-order word is _IO_MAGIC; rest is flags. */

  /* The following pointers correspond to the C++ streambuf protocol. */
  char *_IO_read_ptr;   /* Current read pointer */
  char *_IO_read_end;   /* End of get area. */
  char *_IO_read_base;  /* Start of putback+get area. */
  char *_IO_write_base; /* Start of put area. */
  char *_IO_write_ptr;  /* Current put pointer. */
  char *_IO_write_end;  /* End of put area. */
  char *_IO_buf_base;   /* Start of reserve area. */
  char *_IO_buf_end;    /* End of reserve area. */

  /* The following fields are used to support backing up and undo. */
  char *_IO_save_base; /* Pointer to start of non-current get area. */
  char *_IO_backup_base;  /* Pointer to first valid character of backup area */
  char *_IO_save_end; /* Pointer to end of non-current get area. */

  struct _IO_marker *_markers;

  struct _IO_FILE *_chain;

  int _fileno;
  int _flags2;
  __off_t _old_offset; /* This used to be _offset but it's too small.  */

  /* 1+column number of pbase(); 0 is unknown. */
  unsigned short _cur_column;
  signed char _vtable_offset;
  char _shortbuf[1];

  _IO_lock_t *_lock;
#ifdef _IO_USE_OLD_IO_FILE
};
```

It has different pointers for reading & writing. With `a+` mode, we have `read-pointer` at the beginning & `write-pointer` at the end. As you can see library uses intermediate buffers to optimise `file-IO` calls.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what [`fopen(3)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fopen.3.html) says for it.

> a
>
> Open for appending (writing at end of file).  The file is created if it does not exist.  The stream is positioned at the end of the file.
>
> a+
>
> Open for reading and appending (writing at end of file).
> The file is created if it does not exist.  Output is
> always appended to the end of the file.  POSIX is silent
> on what the initial read position is when using this mode.
> For glibc, the initial file position for reading is at the
> beginning of the file, but for Android/BSD/MacOS, the
> initial file position for reading is at the end of the
> file.

Which means `a+` starts reading from start of the file and writes end of the file(append) but `a` reads and writes end of the file.